# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name available as request attribute - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, binding

I am getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
```

This is the stack trace

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:534)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:452)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>
>
> root cause 
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:141)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
>     org.apache.jsp.student_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(student_jsp.java:182)
>     org.apache.jsp.student_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(student_jsp.java:117)
>     org.apache.jsp.student_jsp._jspService(student_jsp.java:79)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

This is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">


    <display-name>Spring MVC Form Handling</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>student.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-Servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>   

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is my applicationContext.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.Prime" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/JSP/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>



</beans>
```

This is my student.jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Student Information</h2>
<form:form modelAttribute="SpringWeb" method="POST" action="/HelloWeb/addStudent" commandName="SpringWeb">
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my StudentController.java file

```
package com.Prime;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
public class StudentController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView student() {
      return new ModelAndView("/student.jsp", "SpringWeb", new Student());
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Student student, 
   ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
      model.addAttribute("age", student.getAge());
      model.addAttribute("id", student.getId());

      return "result";
   }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this error.... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your configuration and I didnt get your error.
But I had to change something.

The viewResolver is adding .jsp to your view name.
So IMHO you should change

```
 return new ModelAndView("/student.jsp", "SpringWeb", new Student());
```

to

```
 return new ModelAndView("student", "SpringWeb", new Student());
```

So remove jsp and the "/" before student.

Then it worked for me. But as I said I didnt get your error

Comment: The same code I am using but the error is not being resolve...  I am also getting the same error. Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 3):

Edit:

It brothers me that your exceptions states "bean name **'command'**". I think you have some delopyment issue, because the code you posted here does not match the exception.

---

Remove the `commandName` attribute from your form tag, the `modelAttribute` attribute is enought:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="SpringWeb" method="POST" action="/HelloWeb/addStudent" >
```

After reading this [article](http://chompingatbits.com/2009/08/25/spring-formtag-commandname-vs-modelattribute/), it seams that this is not the solution for your problem, but anyway you do not need to specifiy them twice.

Comment: Just a guess, may be because of presence of both `commandName` and `modelAttribute` form is not bind to any object and taglib assuming default modelAttribute named `command`.

Answer (score 0):

The jsp location the call to `/student` is looking for is

```
/WEB-INF/JSP//student.jsp.jsp
```

Change the configuration to match proper url.